# Improving Accessibility: Customising Accordion jQuery and HTML?

Tags: jquery, html, accordion

**Introduction:**

I'm using a Premium Responsive Theme using local installation of WordPress.

The Theme provides an Accordion ShortCode based on jQuery 1.11.0.

**The issue:**

With the 12 point List I've added inline to the ShortCode, mobile users would need to make a few scroll-up gestures to reach the top of the page to close the lengthy Accordion Item in order to make space to see the other Accordion Navigation Options.

**The aim:**

To improve Accessibility I'd like to customise the HTML and jQuery by adding a '*CLOSE*' link at the bottom of each lengthy Accordion Item.

**The problem:**

I can't get the additional `<div id="close-title" class="close-title">CLOSE ^^</div>` to function when placed at the bottom of each Accordion Item.

**My attempts to solve this:**

I added a variable named '`closer`' to the opening jQuery function, which seems to work when the DIV Element with CSS Class `.close-title` is nested within the Class `.toggle-title`. A snippet from the Accordion function:

```
/*  ACCORDION
/*====================================================================*/

    (function($){

        $('.accordion').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this),

                title = $this.find('.toggle-title'),
                closer =  $this.find('.close-title'),
                content =  $this.find('.toggle-content');


                if($this.hasClass('collapsible-yes')){
                    $this.find('.active:not(:first)').removeClass("active");
                }
....
....
```

In fact, the DIV Element with Class `.close-title` behaves exactly the same as `.toggle-title-header` when nested within Class `.toggle-title`, which is a good indication that I'm on the right track.

When I say "behaves", I refer to the way that the Title tabs function with their "+" and "-" which are indicators for states of Open and Close, and each Accordion Item Opens and Closes *on click*.

I believe that the jQuery Script doesn't seem able to *find* the DIV Element with Class `.close-title` when it's nested anywhere other than within DIV Element `.toggle-title`.

**Note:** please see Accordion with Title: 'Trustee role description' in JSBin example to see a demonstration of this nested-related point.

**My question:**

How can I *call* the same function used to Toggle each menu item by clicking on 'CLOSE', and how can I do this by placing `<div id="close-title" class="close-title">CLOSE ^^</div>` at the bottom of the Accordion Item?

**JSBin Example:**

I have this JSBin example: http://jsbin.com/yonox/2/edit - where you'll notice a DIV Element with id & class: `.close-title`. nested at the top, and at the bottom within Comment `<!--START ACCORDION TAB 3-->`. The DIV placed at the top works, the DIV at the bottom does not work.

Could someone please demonstrate how I would make this Element Toggle the Item in the same way as the "Title +/-" Elements do, given that this Element should ideally be positioned at the bottom of each Accordion Item.

**For our Information, here is a snippet from the original Short Code for the Accordion Menu:**

```
[accordion collapsible="yes no"]

[toggle title="What do I need to know if I’m thinking of becoming a trustee?" open="no"]

Charity Trustees are responsible for controlling the management and administration of the charity. In general terms trustees are responsible for the proper administration of the charity in accordance with the law, and its trusts as set out in the governing document.

Their overriding duty is to pursue the objectives of the charity and ensure that income and property are used exclusively for these objectives.

The general duties of a trustee are set out in the common law and statute.

[/toggle]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many solution for this kind of issue,
one of the solution i am trying to list down,
Here it goes

Add a close me div inside your lengthy toggle-content div as:

```
<div class="close-me" style="color:red;">Close Me ^ </div>
```

Note: Please make sure that your have inserted this close me div inside your toggle-content div and must be the last child of the toggle-content div.

and add the below in the end of your java script file:

```
$('.close-me').click(function(){
  $(this).parent('div.toggle-content').prev().click();
});
```

I hope this solutions may solve your problem.

Comment: I just tested in my above JSBin and this works. I added your additions to the end of each toggle-content div, and `Close Me ^` also toggles just as my original Accordion Title and +/- do. Next: I'll try this on the live site.